# Problem for use dynamic components with ng-template

Tags: angular, components, ng-content

I have problem (context I think), for use dynamical component with ng-template.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-wlv9rj?file=app/guidelines/guidelines.component.ts

I'm not understood what I'm doing wrong, but I think it's a problem of Hook.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to query `@ViewChild('areaContainer')` before you have the `#areaContainer` element rendered, because `#guideline_1` template is not yet active. that is why it is undefined. first render `#guideline_1` template, and then, inside of it you can refer to the #areaContainer

Comment: Thanks you now I understand my error.
How can I be sure of my #guideline_1 is ready before query areaContainer?